# List divide based on element from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists as follows

```
a = [646, 650, 654, 658, 662, 666, 670, 674, 678, 682, 686, 690, 694, 698, 702, 706, 13565, 13569, 13573, 13577, 13581, 13585, 13589, 13593, 13597, 13601, 13605, 13609, 13613, 13617, 13621, 13625, 13629, 13633, 13637, 13641, 13645, 13649, 13653, 13657, 13661, 21237, 21241, 21245, 21249, 21253, 21257, 21261, 21265, 21269, 21273, 21277, 21281, 21285, 21289, 21293, 21297, 21301, 21305, 21309, 21313, 21317, 21321, 21325, 21329, 21333, 21337, 21341, 21345]

b = [646, 706, 13661, 21345]
```

So basically I want to break list `a` into smaller chunks based on start stop values from list `b`. E.g.
Something like this

```
[
[646, 650, 654, 658, 662, 666, 670, 674, 678, 682, 686, 690, 694, 698, 702, 706],
[13565, 13569, 13573, 13577, 13581, 13585, 13589, 13593, 13597, 13601, 13605, 13609, 13613, 13617, 13621, 13625, 13629, 13633, 13637, 13641, 13645, 13649, 13653, 13657, 13661],
[21237, 21241, 21245, 21249, 21253, 21257, 21261, 21265, 21269, 21273, 21277, 21281, 21285, 21289, 21293, 21297, 21301, 21305, 21309, 21313, 21317, 21321, 21325, 21329, 21333, 21337, 21341, 21345]
]
```

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: What would you want to happen if the "stop" value in *list b* is not found in *list a*? Also, are the values in both lists sorted in ascending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example I understand you want that the first interval includes the boundaries ([646, 706]) while the others must include only the upper boundary (]706, 13661], ]13661, 21345]).

I here use the .index method and a for loop that considers the lower boundary of the first interval and excludes it for the others:

```
lists_result = []

for i in range(len(b[:-1])):
    idx_inf = a.index(b[i])
    idx_sup = a.index(b[i+1])
    if i == 0:
        lists_result.append(a[idx_inf:idx_sup+1])
    else:
        lists_result.append(a[idx_inf+1:idx_sup+1])
```

Comment: This solution gives all the lists properly. Thank you, @CorradoB

Comment: @MeghaSirisilla This solution relies on the fact that the elements of `b` occur in `a`, and works well if that assumption holds. Was that actually your intention?

Comment: yes...all the elements of b will always be present in a. It will never differ.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1: use bisect

I would solve this problem by using the `bisect` module to find where each item in `a` would be inserted in `b` to determine which bin an item belongs to.

This solution does not require that `a` be sorted, but it does require that `b` be sorted.

```
bin_boundaries = sorted(b)
results = [[] for _ in range(len(bin_boundaries)+1)]
for i in a:
    pos = bisect.bisect_left(bin_boundaries, i)
    results[pos].append(i)
print(results)
```

Now, you did not specify whether you wanted an item that was equal to the boundary in the previous or next bin. I placed it in the previous bin. If you meant the next, replace `bisect_left` by `bisect_right` above.

I also output two more bins that your expected output shows: the first bin has items smaller than the first bin boundary, and the last bin items greater than the last boundary. Add `results = results[1:-1]` if you want to remove those edge bins.

### Solution 2: just loop over the list for each bin

Now, here's a much simpler solution that just traverses `a` for each bin:

```
bin_boundaries = sorted(b)
results = []
for low, high in zip(bin_boundaries[:-1], bin_boundaries[1:]):
    results.append([i for i in a if i > low and i <= high])
print(results)
```

This time, I didn't create the edge bins. Again, fix the `>` and `<=` to match the semantics you actually want at the edges.

That outer loop can also be turned into a list comprehension, to give you this nested list comprehension and a very compact solution:

```
results = [
    [i for i in a if i > low and i <= high]
    for low, high in zip(bin_boundaries[:-1], bin_boundaries[1:])
]
```

Comment: Thanks...this solved my problem. Just a small question...why does 646 come as a standalone list in solution one or it is not included at all in the rest of the list solutions? @joanis

Comment: @MeghaSirisilla That is because you didn't specify how you wanted to deal with a number that is equal to the boundary: with `b=[646, 706...]`, does 646 belong in the first bin or before the first bin? Does 706 belong in the first bin or the second bin? In your expected output, you give inconsistent answers: either 646 is before the first bin, and 706 is in the first bin, or 646 is in the 1st bin and 706 in the second. Tell me which you want and I can fix the answer. Or adjust my code as I suggested in my solution, based on your answer to that question.

Comment: in my expected output as well I have started my first bin from 646 and it ends with 706. Both are the first and last element of the first bin. This is how I want it. 646 to be the start of the first bin and 706 to be the end. If you can edit your answer I will be grateful. Thanks.